# Could not execute dotnet swagger command

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, dotnet-tool

I'm trying to execute the `dotnet swagger` command but received an error message:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-swagger does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

- The swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli (5.0.0) tool is installed globally.
- The PATH to the tools is set.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does running `dotnet tool list` and `dotnet tool list -g` show?

Comment: @Kevin Smith 
`dotnet tool list` shows an empty list,
`dotnet tool list -g` shows the installed `swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli` tool

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command is no longer `dotnet swagger`. It is `swagger` only.

[image]