# generate swagger file with dotnet swagger command for azure functions

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am trying to generate swagger file using dotnet swagger command for my azure functions but getting error runtimeconfig.json does not exist. Please guide me on this on how to generate swagger file for azure functions using dotnet swagger command.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ways for this

**WAY -1**
Please check if you are giving the correct command. The command is no longer  `dotnet swagger`. It is  `swagger`  only.

[image]

You can find more information in the SO Threads you can refer more [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819993/could-not-execute-dotnet-swagger-command) which discusses the similar related issue.

**WAY-2**
You can leverage the following approach which is to use APIM along with Functions. These APIs are described using an OpenAPI definition. This JSON / YAML file contains information on what operations are available in an API. By integrating your function app, you can have API Management generate these OpenAPI definitions.

> Steps to follow in order to get the OpenAPI definition
>
> 1. Create the API Management Instance and hence it enables the `Enable Application Insights` option. As so, we can send the logs to the same place as function Application.
> 2. Import your HTTP triggered function endpoints.
> 3. Now you can download the OpenAPI definition from API Management instance.

Refer the following [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition) to get a step by step procedure

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will go through them.

Comment: I am trying to do this automation for APIM only. In my scenario I am trying to generate the swagger file automatically and by the help of ARM template, I am trying to automate the update of APIM APIs.